# Get daily number of call API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have django rest framwork support android, ios, web with some version different api and different version mobile app. Now i hope know how many time each api call in 1 day, 1 month....for optimize and remove unused api.

My question is: how to know each api call how many time in 1 day? Have any library support it or any way do it. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you are using Nginx or Apache web server in front of your app server, so both these web servers already logs each access request they got. You can use that log file for doing analyzing the api call usage pattern.

Comment: im using elasticbeanstalk

Comment: You can explore this django package https://github.com/Rhumbix/django-request-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try [silk](https://silk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).It is one of best package for api tracking and logs**

[image]

Comment: i tried and have error `Reverse for 'summary' not found. 'summary' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`. Im google and tried fix with on off Debug, change position import url... but cant help

Comment: please impliment step by step and dont forget  make migrations and migrate. I have already used this package many time..but did not get this error.